# compare values of foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to check if the value of $first[0] in each foreach is unique or does already exists in another foreach. But I have to compare it outside of the foreach.

Is this possible?

```
<?php foreach($instagram_array['items'] as $image) { ?>
    <div class = "tag" >
        <img src = "<?php echo $image['images']['low_resolution']['url'] ?>" width = "250px" >
        <?php
            $first = explode(" ", $image['caption']['text']);
            echo $first[0];
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Did you try `in_array` function?

Comment: yeah but i have to compare it outside of the foreach loop

Comment: I think what you need here is `array_intersection` instead of `in_array`, all you need to do is to check what is the intersection, Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Although it's not directly related to your problem; why do you space out the source of the image like that? It's a little misleading and confusing at first glance.

Comment: @ElliotMiller I edited your code to make it cleaner. I would suggest not switching back and forth between HTML and PHP so often. It makes the code very hard to decipher.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of foreach"? Do you mean you need the result after the foreach loop finishes executing? Also: where is "another foreach"? I only see one foreach loop in the code.